# Multiple ratings in the same post

Tags: wordpress, rating

I have a wordpress site where I in one single post have a list of restaurants. There is over 50 rows, and it's growing.

I would really love to be able to add a star rating to each row, but I haven't found any rating plugins that are able to have multiple ratings in the same post, because they all are based on post id.

Is there anyone out there that know of any way to add a rating to each of the rows in this post: http://www.lchfarkivet.se/lchf-restauranger-sverige/

Or if it's not possible to add a rating system, then maybe a heart or thumbs up or down... Something that my readers are able to use to add a rating in some way.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Do you have a (consistent) unique identifier for your rows (I can't see one looking at the page source)?  If not, it'll be difficult to do (whether you do a rating or a thumbs up/down).  If it's not too much work, I'd look at making `restaurant` a [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) and pulling them in.  That'd give you the post ID you need to use one of the plugins you've found.

Comment: Similarly to Hobo I'd have each restaurant in a single post, then use a category page or tag to group all together, then you can use default star plugins to rate them. Then adding new restaurants, removing, sorting them by name, date, stars etc will be much easier.